# What's wrong with this initialization? Why can't I succeed when I try to initialize a graph using the initialization function

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, initialization

using VS,C language.
I try to initialization a Graph structure by a initialize fuction

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> #define maxint 1000
> #define mvnum 100
> typedef struct
> {
>   int vexs[mvnum];
>   int edges[mvnum][mvnum];
>   int n, e;
> }MGraph;
> void creatUDN(MGraph *G) {
>   G = (MGraph*)malloc(sizeof(MGraph));
>   int i, j, k, w;
>   scanf_s("%d", &(G->n));
>   scanf_s("%d", &(G->e));
>   for (i = 0; i < G->n; i++)
>       scanf_s("%d", &(G->vexs[i]));
>   for (i = 0; i < G->n; ++i)
>       for (j = 0; j < G->n; ++j)
>           G->edges[i][j] = maxint;
>   for (k = 0; k < G->e; k++)
>   {
>       scanf_s("%d %d %d", &i, &j, &w);
>       G->edges[i-1][j-1] = w;
>   }
>   for (i = 0; i < G->n; ++i)
>   {
>       for (j = 0; j <G->n; ++j)
>           printf("%d\t", G->edges[i][j]);
>       printf("\n");
>   }
> }
> ```

this is main function

```
    int main()
{
  MGraph *g;
  g=(MGraph*)malloc(sizeof(MGraph));
  creatUDN(g);
  **printf("%d", g->e);**
}
```

It shows that g still a Nullpointer after initialize.
why?

Comment: Why are allocating `g` in `main` and in `createUDN`?

Comment: Assigning to the `G` variable in `createUDN` has no effect on the `g` variable in `main`. That's probably your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the assignment to `G` in `creatUDN`.

```
G = (MGraph*)malloc(sizeof(MGraph));
```

Now your code will work.

You correctly allocated this data structure in `main` and passed the pointer to `creatUDN`, but then for some reason you allocated it again in `creatUDN` so the data structure you allocated in `main` remains unchanged.

The other way you can do this is to **return** the allocated data structure from `creatUDN`. That would look like this

```
MGraph *creatUDN() {
  G = (MGraph*)malloc(sizeof(MGraph));
  ...
  return G;
}

int main()
{
  MGraph *g = creatUDN();
  printf("%d", g->e);
}
```

You seem to have written something that's half way between these two methods.